# How to call a helper function from a library class

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a library class "Weekprint.php" (libraries/Weekprint.php) and in a helper file (calendar_helper.php) I have function like

```
print_calendar($start, $events, $cal_type).
```

I can use them separately,

I wonder if/how I can call print_calendar from Weekprint.

I use Codeigniter 3.1.5

Comment: You can edit Weekprint.php?

Comment: Yes, I can edit it, like a normal file.

Comment: Properly set up helper files do not have classes to encapsulate methods.  Helper files are just a bunch of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it,

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('calendar_helper');
```

Inside the library Weekprint.php

Answer (score 0):

You can call the helper from the library. The helper needs to be loaded before it can be used. Pick the logical spot in Weekprint.php to do that in the usual way.

```
$this->load->helper('calendar_helper');
```

After that, you can call it in the usual way when needed.

```
print_calendar($start, $events, $cal_type);
```

Obviously, the various arguments to the helper function need to be assigned values.

Comment: I got Message: Undefined property: Weekprint::$load